# How to disable SVN auto association in subclipse plugins

Tags: java, eclipse, svn, subclipse

I would like to know is it possible to disable auto association to SVN for imported projects? I do have SVN plugins installed in my eclipse from

`http://subclipse.tig​ris.org/svn/subclips​e/trunk/www/update_1​.12.x
version 1.10.13`

When I am importing some projects, e.g. from git, I am getting following Error Log.

```
!ENTRY org.tigris.subversion.subclipse.core 4 0 2016-09-27 12:37:06.343
!MESSAGE Could not auto-share project MY_PROJECT
!STACK 1
 org.tigris.subversion.subclipse.core.SVNException: Provided SVN information does not match that on disk for project 'MY_PROJECT'.
            at org.tigris.subversion.subclipse.core.resources.SVNWorkspaceRoot.setSharing(SVNWorkspaceRoot.java:206)
            at org.tigris.subversion.subclipse.core.SVNTeamProviderType$AutoShareJob.autoconnectSVNProject(SVNTeamProviderType.java:140)
            at org.tigris.subversion.subclipse.core.SVNTeamProviderType$AutoShareJob.run(SVNTeamProviderType.java:106)
            at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:55)
!SUBENTRY 1 org.tigris.subversion.subclipse.core 4 4 2016-09-27 12:37:06.345
!MESSAGE Provided SVN information does not match that on disk for project 'MY_PROJECT'.
```

I have posted same question a year ago on [https://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/t/1064934/](https://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/t/1064934/http://)

The big problem is that my sources are having many symbolic links and when svn tries to auto associate, it goes into an endless loop and I am getting java out of memory error.

The project itself is imported with predefined filters that allows me to browse project files without any problem. Only SVN is causing the problem.

Is there a way to disable SVN auto association in subclipse ?

Thank you in advance, 
Any help will be appreciated. 
Lidia

Answer (score 0):

The link you provide does have a solution posted

"suggesting you to just disable the feature at:
Window->Preferences->Team->SVN->Enable automatic project share"

I had the same issue and this resolved it for me.

Comment: I didn't said that it has a solution. I still do not have a solution for this issue using subclipse.